# Issue creating a custom, virtual, on screen keyboard in React using CSS grid. Not all buttons display

Tags: css, reactjs, keyboard

I am trying to create an on screen keyboard for a React application using CSS grid to divide up the  container it is in. As far as I can work out I have set the display properties and the grid template as required, but for some reason it is only displaying 4 buttons with most of them hidden underneath the one in the bottom right hand corner. As seen above.

If I make the grid template smaller, I get more buttons, but if I make it any bigger, it goes back to the above.

Here is my Component code.

```
import React from "react";
import "../CSS/Keyboard.css";

const OnScreenKeyboard = () => {
  const handleKeyClick = (character) => {
    // Placeholder code: Insert the character into the input field
  };

  return (
    <div className="on-screen-keyboard">
      <button className="Q" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("q")}>
        q
      </button>
      <button className="W" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("w")}>
        w
      </button>
      <button className="E" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("e")}>
        e
      </button>
      <button className="R" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("r")}>
        r
      </button>
      <button className="T" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("t")}>
        t
      </button>
      <button className="Y" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("y")}>
        y
      </button>
      <button className="U" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("u")}>
        u
      </button>
      <button className="I" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("i")}>
        i
      </button>
      <button className="O" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("o")}>
        o
      </button>
      <button className="P" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("p")}>
        p
      </button>
      <button className="backspace-button">Backspace</button>

      <button className="caps-button">Caps</button>
      <button className="A" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("a")}>
        a
      </button>
      <button className="S" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("s")}>
        s
      </button>
      <button className="D" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("d")}>
        d
      </button>
      <button className="F" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("f")}>
        f
      </button>
      <button className="G" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("g")}>
        g
      </button>
      <button className="H" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("h")}>
        h
      </button>
      <button className="J" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("j")}>
        j
      </button>
      <button className="K" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("k")}>
        k
      </button>
      <button className="L" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("l")}>
        l
      </button>
      <button className="L" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("'")}>
        '
      </button>

      <button className="shift-button">Shift</button>
      <button className="Z" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("z")}>
        z
      </button>
      <button className="X" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("x")}>
        x
      </button>
      <button className="C" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("c")}>
        c
      </button>
      <button className="V" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("v")}>
        v
      </button>
      <button className="B" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("b")}>
        b
      </button>
      <button className="N" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("n")}>
        n
      </button>
      <button className="M" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("m")}>
        m
      </button>
      <button className="commma-button" onClick={() => handleKeyClick(",")}>
        ,
      </button>
      <button className="fullstop-button" onClick={() => handleKeyClick(".")}>
        .
      </button>

      <button className="special-characters-button">.?123</button>
      <button className="emojis-button"></button>
      <button className="space-button" onClick={() => handleKeyClick(" ")}>
        Space
      </button>
      <button className="left-button">Left</button>
      <button className="right-button">Right</button>
      <button className="special-characters-button">.?123</button>
      <button className="enter-button" onClick={() => handleKeyClick("\n")}>
        Enter
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default OnScreenKeyboard;
```

And here is the CSS file that goes with it. I have commented out the grid I used to get more buttons so you can see what I tried.

```
.on-screen-keyboard {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1fr, 44);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1fr, 4);
  /* grid:
    "Q W E R T"
    "Caps A S D F"
    "Shift Z XX C V"
    "Special Emoji Space Left Right"; */
  grid-template-areas:
    "Q Q Q Q W W W W E E E E R R R R T T T T YY YY YY YY U U U U I I I I O O O O P P P P Backspace Backspace Backspace Backspace"
    "Q Q Q Q W W W W E E E E R R R R T T T T YY YY YY YY U U U U I I I I O O O O P P P P Backspace Backspace Backspace Backspace"
    "Caps Caps A A A A S S S S D D D D F F F F G G G G H H H H J J J J K K K K L L L L ' ' Enter Enter Enter Enter"
    "Caps Caps A A A A S S S S D D D D F F F F G G G G H H H H J J J J K K K K L L L L ' ' Enter Enter Enter Enter"
    "Shift Shift Shift Shift Z Z Z Z XX XX XX XX C C C C V V V V B B B B N N N N M M M M Comma Comma Comma Comma FullStop FullStop FullStop FullStop Enter Enter Enter Enter"
    "Shift Shift Shift Shift Z Z Z Z XX XX XX XX C C C C V V V V B B B B N N N N M M M M Comma Comma Comma Comma FullStop FullStop FullStop FullStop Enter Enter Enter Enter"
    "Special Special Special Special Emoji Emoji Emoji Emoji Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Left Left Left Left Right Right Right Right Special Special Special Special Enter Enter Enter Enter"
    "Special Special Special Special Emoji Emoji Emoji Emoji Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Space Left Left Left Left Right Right Right Right Special Special Special Special Enter Enter Enter Enter";
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 500px; /* Adjust min-width as needed for responsiveness */
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* 
.keyboard-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
} */

button {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.Q {
  grid-area: Q;
}

.W {
  grid-area: W;
}

.E {
  grid-area: E;
}

.R {
  grid-area: R;
}

.T {
  grid-area: T;
}

.Y {
  grid-area: YY;
}

.U {
  grid-area: U;
}

.I {
  grid-area: I;
}

.O {
  grid-area: O;
}

.P {
  grid-area: P;
}

.A {
  grid-area: A;
}

.S {
  grid-area: S;
}

.D {
  grid-area: D;
}

.F {
  grid-area: F;
}

.G {
  grid-area: G;
}

.H {
  grid-area: H;
}

.J {
  grid-area: J;
}

.K {
  grid-area: K;
}

.L {
  grid-area: L;
}

.Z {
  grid-area: Z;
}

.X {
  grid-area: XX;
}

.C {
  grid-area: C;
}

.V {
  grid-area: V;
}

.B {
  grid-area: B;
}

.N {
  grid-area: N;
}

.M {
  grid-area: M;
}

.comma-button {
  grid-area: Comma;
}

.fullstop-button {
  grid-area: FullStop;
}

.left-button {
  grid-area: LeftArrow;
}

.right-button {
  grid-area: RightArrow;
}

/* Shift button styles */
.shift-button {
  grid-area: Shift;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Special characters button styles */
.special-characters-button {
  grid-area: Special;
}

/* Emojis button styles */
.emojis-button {
  grid-area: Emoji;
}

/* Backspace button styles */
.backspace-button {
  grid-area: Backspace;
  color: #ff0000; /* Red color for backspace */
}

/* Space button styles */
.space-button {
  grid-area: Space;
}

/* Enter button styles */
.enter-button {
  grid-area: Enter;
  background-color: #00ff00; /* Green color for enter */
}
```

I have tried lots of things. including adding templates for the columns and rows, but nothing seems to be doing the trick. Maybe I just can't have the number of columns that I want?

Any help that you can give me is very much appreciated. I hope that it is something silly I have done, but I can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things which are not matching up your HTML with your CSS.

1. your `'` key has the className `L` instead of it's own class and styling.
2. some classes do not have defined a grid-area like the `caps-button`

In your CSS you want to repeat each row with `44` times `1fr` but have the parameters backwards, it should be `grid-template-columns: repeat(44, 1fr);`

By saying this it does mean **each** row of your `grid-template-areas` should have 44 items in there, else the browser will not accept it.

You can see the working demo at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/keyboard-7ytwpd)

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I really appreciate it. This has got me very close, but I still have a couple of issues. The first is that some of the buttons are filling more space that others given the same amount of grid area. This is where I have got to in the sandbox... [Link] (https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/keyboard-forked-pd6qsc?file=%2Fstyles.css%3A3%2C2-5%2C23) _italic_ **bold** 'here'.

Comment: The second issue is using the same css grid area set up, I don't seem to be able to make this work in my react component. It just stacks up all the buttons underneath the Enter button in the bottom right hand corner. If I use template rows and column properties, i can see all the grid areas when inspecting, but when I don't it doesn't show them either. The inspector is saying the grid template area is an invalid property so ruling it out.